# Ping Batch file with color indicator and log to file

Tags: batch-file, ping

i have script

```
echo off & cls

TITLE = PING KE google.com

:top

ping -n 1 google.com | FIND "TTL="

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET OUT=4F & echo Request timed out.) ELSE (SET OUT=2F)

color %OUT%

ping -n 3 -w 500 127.0.0.1 >nul

GoTo top
```

i waant to add log file. any body help  me? how to add log file in my script?
thank's for help

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: @Markus finding help in a language other than your native language makes it difficult for people to ask a question correctly, so I try and help instead of down vote.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, a citation from the help page [ask]: *»If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you.«* Questions have to be clear, otherwise they do not contribute any particular value to this site...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, and I get that, but sometimes we try and help without worrying to much about the rules. :) not fighting by the ways. was just stating something.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understaning correctly, this is what you want?
Just change which lines you want to log.

```
echo off & cls
TITLE = PING KE google.com
:top
 ping -n 1 google.com | FIND "TTL=" >>Logfile.txt
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET OUT=4F & echo Request timed out.) ELSE (SET OUT=2F)
 color %OUT%
 echo Color set to %OUT% >>Logfile.txt
 ping -n 3 -w 500 127.0.0.1 >>Logfile.txt
GoTo top
```

Comment: The two redirections in one line don't make sense, the second one `>>Logfile.txt` overrides the first `>NUL`. Reverse the order to proof yourself.

Comment: @LotPings The >null does not display to console, but >> file.txt will still print to logfile.

Comment: There is only one standard output and the last redirection 'wins'

Comment: Not really, I get your point, but if you do: `ping 127.0.0.1 >nul >> test.txt` it will run command, not display to console, but log to file. So in this case, he might want to do pings in the background but not show on console, only change console color, but still log everything to a file. That being said, doing ping `127.0.0.1 >> file.txt` will also not display to console,